# Undefined variable in contact form on lines 21 and 27

Tags: php

Until now, the PHP code below for a contact form has worked perfectly but my error log file suddenly says there is an undefined variable message on line 21 and sometimes on line 27.

```
<?php
$to = "name@email.com"; //This is the email address you want to send the email to
$subject_prefix = "Enquiry"; //Use this if you want to have a prefix before the subject

if(!isset($_GET['action']))
{
    die("You must not access this page directly!"); //Just to stop people from visiting get-in-touch.php normally
}

/* Now lets trim up the input before sending it */

$fname = trim($_GET['fname']); //The senders name
$lname = trim($_GET['lname']); //The senders lname
$email_id = trim($_GET['email_id']); //The senders email id
$pphone = trim($_GET['pphone']); //The senders phone
$cname = trim($_GET['cname']);  //The senders message
$subject = trim($_GET['subject']);  //The senders subject

$message = "".$message."\n Nmae: ".$fname."\n Address: ".$lname."\n Email: ".$email_id. "\n Phone: ".$pphone."\n Commient: ".$cname."\n subject: ".$subject;

$headers = "From: ".$email_id."";
//$headers .= 'Bcc: name@email.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); //a very simple send

echo 'Thank you '.$name.', your email has been sent.'; 
//now lets update the "contactarea" div on the contact.html page. The contactarea| tell's the javascript which div to update.
?>
```

Comment: And which are lines 21 and 27? What does the submit form look like? Debug per `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: Do you understand we cannot see line numbers, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$message` before its defined. Add `$message = '';` before `$message = ....(something);` Why is `$message` concatenated in the message itself in your case?

Fixed code;

```
<?php
$to = "name@email.com"; //This is the email address you want to send the email to
$subject_prefix = "Enquiry"; //Use this if you want to have a prefix before the subject

if(!isset($_GET['action']))
{
    die("You must not access this page directly!"); //Just to stop people from visiting get-in-touch.php normally
}

/* Now lets trim up the input before sending it */

$fname = trim($_GET['fname']); //The senders name
$lname = trim($_GET['lname']); //The senders lname
$email_id = trim($_GET['email_id']); //The senders email id
$pphone = trim($_GET['pphone']); //The senders phone
$cname = trim($_GET['cname']);  //The senders message
$subject = trim($_GET['subject']);  //The senders subject

$message = '';
$message = "".$message."\n Nmae: ".$fname."\n Address: ".$lname."\n Email: ".$email_id. "\n Phone: ".$pphone."\n Commient: ".$cname."\n subject: ".$subject;

$headers = "From: ".$email_id."";
//$headers .= 'Bcc: name@email.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); //a very simple send

echo 'Thank you '.$name.', your email has been sent.'; 
//now lets update the "contactarea" div on the contact.html page. The contactarea| tell's the javascript which div to update.


?>
```

By the way: `$subject_prefix` is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Your using `$message` in the wrong place.

**Few things**:

- Why your using `$_GET` without `$_POST?`. I would suggest you to use
  `$_POST` since your dealing with user information.`$_GET` may be used for sending non-sensitive data.

Also i would like to suggest you to **close the brackets**. Because using **brackets** does help to make it easier to track where blocks start and end.

```
$to = "name@email.com"; //This is the email address you want to send the email to
$subject_prefix = "Enquiry"; //Use this if you want to have a prefix before the subject
if (!isset($_GET['action'])) {
    die("You must not access this page directly!"); //Just to stop people from visiting get-in-touch.php normally
}
else {
    /* Now lets trim up the input before sending it */
    $fname = trim($_GET['fname']); //The senders name
    $lname = trim($_GET['lname']); //The senders lname
    $email_id = trim($_GET['email_id']); //The senders email id
    $pphone = trim($_GET['pphone']); //The senders phone
    $cname = trim($_GET['cname']); //The senders message
    $subject = trim($_GET['subject']); //The senders subject
    $message = "Name: " . $fname . "\n Address: " . $lname . "\n Email: " . $email_id . "\n Phone: " . $pphone . "\n Commient: " . $cname . "\n subject: " . $subject;
    $headers = "From: " . $email_id . "";
    // $headers .= 'Bcc: name@email.com' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //a very simple send
    echo 'Thank you ' . $name . ', your email has been sent.';
    // now lets update the "contactarea" div on the contact.html page. The contactarea| tell's the javascript which div to update.
}
```

Comment: The `else` is completely useless, as for the braces they're useful but, in this case, also useless.  In regards to `$_POST` vs `$_GET` I agree with you.

Comment: @PedroLobito agree..But just wanted to tell about the use braces..When it comes to huge code it would be a good practice.